# Forcing a Mongoid model to always use a specific database

Tags: mongoid

I have this in my 2 models:

```rb
class Weather
  include Mongoid::Document
  store_in database: ->{ "myapp_shared_#{Rails.env}" }
  ...
```

```rb
class Event
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :weather
  ...
```

This is a multi-tenant app, so I have this in my application controller, to change the database based on subdomain:

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :switch_database

  def switch_database
    Mongoid.override_database("myapp_#{subdomain_name}_#{Rails.env}")
  end
  ...
```

Now when I run Event.first.weather, I see this in my debug log:

```
D, [2015-09-03T18:38:18] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | myapp_subdomain_development.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"events", "filter"=>{}}
D, [2015-09-03T18:38:18] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | myapp_subdomain_development.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.025892s
D, [2015-09-03T18:38:18] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | myapp_subdomain_development.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"weathers", "filter"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5522c1d9526f6d6b9f0c0000')}}
D, [2015-09-03T18:38:18] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | myapp_subdomain_development.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.00078s
```

So weather is searched in the override_database, not in the store_in database. If I do not run Mongoid.override_database, then the weather is taken from the app_shared_development database as specified in store_in.

The question is, how do I use override_database as this is a multi-tenant app, but still force certain models to always use the shared database?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the best solution is to stop using override_database altogether. It has too many side effects and unintentional consequences.

I have simplified the following code, but in essence these were the steps:

1) I have abstracted all of my models to inherit from another class which looks a bit like this:

```rb
module XanModel
  module Base
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    include Mongoid::Document

    included do
      store_in database: -> { DatabaseSwitcher.current_database_name }
    end
```

2) Then in my model:

```rb
class Event
  include XanModel::Base
```

3) The application controller has this:

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_database

  def set_database
    DatabaseSwitcher.switch_to(subdomain)
  end
```

4) The DatabaseSwitcher has:

```rb
class DatabaseSwitcher
  def self.switch_to(database_name)
    Thread.current[:database_name] = database_name
  end

  def self.current_database_name
    Thread.current[:database_name] || \
      Mongoid::Threaded.database_override || \
      "xanview" # fallback
  end
```

The end result is the application automatically switches databases based on subdomains but certain models can use a global shared database.